# Simplest C++ Example to verify my compiler is c++14 compliant?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

I am taking a class next week on C++11/14 and need to verify that my design tools are up to date and can actually compile C++11/14.

What is the simplest piece of code that I can put together to verify that I can actually compile and execute C++11/14 code on my Linux box?  I know I need GCC 4.9.X or better, but I want to just be sure that everything is jiving before I show up.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you compile with `-std=c++14`? That's about the simplest I can get!

Comment: `int main() {}`

Comment: So all I need is to add the flag and everything is OK?  There no need to add a C++11/14 feature in there?

Comment: @It'sPete , surely there can be compiler bugs, but it makes sense to me that if you can compile with that flag, the compiler you're using supports C++14

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can initially compile with `-std=c++14`. If your gcc (or clang) is not c++14 compliant then compilation will fail (due to uknown flag) :

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++14'
```

Regarding feature availability (querying the existence of specific features), you can perform **feature testing**. An example document can be found [**here**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3694.htm) : it all boils down to the use of macros to test the availability of the specified feature (therein you can also find **what features to look for**).

So even if you want to build with several compilers you can write code like this (naive example follows) :

```
#if __cpp_constexpr
constexpr 
#endif
int triple(int k) { return 3*k; } // compiles with c++98 as well
```

which is how cross platform developing overcomes the joys of supporting multiple compilers and their versions (more elaborate examples would show supporting sth one way in gcc and another way in cl due to different speed of standard implementation)

Comment: I knew it! Thanks for making it an answer =)

Comment: do a `gcc --version` and look at https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html the same for clang and http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: @Alex That's a good way. Albeit it works in a single machine or a "one tool toolchain". If you're building against multiple compilers (or if **planning to support multiple compilers**) you'll need feature testing. Example : I want to support rvalue refs wherever possible but not break compilation for older compilers; one solution is to put that code in `#if __cpp_rvalue_reference` (almost any macro needed is described in the link). **The cool thing is that such macros can cross the boundaries between cl (microsoft) and gcc/clang**

Comment: I think the OP wants to know for his machine and the one he's working for. there is no point in having feature testing macros for a classroom because the op won't write that needs to run on multiple compilers, but needs to run on the grading computer. if his code would be submitted to any codebase in the wild (i.e. boost) feature testing is the way to go (and it's actually a nice solution).

Comment: Not every compiler supports the SG10 feature testing macros. MSVC has no plans to implement them, for instance.

Comment: @T.C. Yep, that's why I'm saying "An example document", I found elaborating beyong this superfluous. If my wording is misleading I could rephrase

Answer (score 10):

The `__cplusplus` macro contains the C++ standard that the compiler is using. Each version of C++ has a specific value for this define. These may (counter intuitively) not match exactly with the name of the standard, so you can use gcc to determine what the values are. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("%ld\n", __cplusplus);
}
```

Compiled like so:

```
g++ -std=c++98 file.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp
g++ -std=c++14 file.cpp
```

Gives the following respectively when run:

```
199711
201103
201300
```

You can then use the predefined macros to generate errors if the value you're looking for isn't available. For example:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201300
#error I require C++14 for this code, so die.
#endif
// ...
```

Then `g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp` will fail compilation.

Answer (score 4):

To be sure it works you can simple try to compile some code available only since c++14. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

auto f() // this function returns multiple values
{
    int x = 5;
    return std::make_tuple(x, 7); // not "return {x,7};" because the corresponding
                                  // tuple constructor is explicit (LWG 2051)
}

int main()
{
    // heterogeneous tuple construction
    int n = 1;
    auto t = std::make_tuple(10, "Test", 3.14, std::ref(n), n);
    n = 7;
    std::cout << "The value of t is "  << "("
              << std::get<0>(t) << ", " << std::get<1>(t) << ", "
              << std::get<2>(t) << ", " << std::get<3>(t) << ", "
              << std::get<4>(t) << ")\n";

    // function returning multiple values
    int a, b;
    std::tie(a, b) = f();
    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

If this does work than you have the right setup :D Hope this helps

Comment: I had no idea heterogenous tuple construction was 14 feature! ( I thought it was 11 ) Thanks for the insight =)

Comment: Can''t see any c++14 specific features used in this code. c++11 standard is sufficient to compile it correctly.

Comment: @Alejandro I'm no longer sure now :-( ... `make_tuple()` could well be c++14 as mentioned (I didn't spot it at 1st)

Comment: It seems like there is make_tuple() support in c++11 as well in some conditions. So I slightly (auto return) modified my answer to stay sure. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

Compiling with flag -std=c++11 or -std=c++14 as per Nikos answer can determine if the compiler supports these standards.

---

Small examples using C++11 and C++14:
For C++11, you could try compiling auto with -std=c++11:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto p1 = make_shared<int>(42);
    // use p1
}
```

For C++14, try using auto as return type with -std=c++14:

```
auto func(int i)
{
    return [i=std::move(i)](int b){return b+i;};
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int num = func(3)(5);
    // use num
}
```

Comment: Standard compliance requires more than one feature. It requires that the compiler/library implement the *entire* standard. All you can say after this test  (or @yakk's) is that you have a compiler which implements a bit of the standard.

Comment: @rici Yes, I have edited answer to avoid misunderstandings.